# When wanting to mount Huawai EVA-L09, it shows CDROM only

Tags: usb, mount, android

I want to access a Huawai P9 from Linux. I know that it did work once in the past a while ago. But now I am puzzled, that the kernel only shows a detected CDROM device.

```
[13606.941299] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[13607.091541] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=107e, bcdDevice= 2.99
[13607.091549] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[13607.091553] usb 1-3: Product: EVA-L09
[13607.091556] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[13607.091559] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: MWS0216817007021
[13607.096252] usb-storage 1-3:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[13607.096957] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-3:1.1
[13608.102255] scsi 2:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Linux    File-CD Gadget   0401 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[13608.103724] sr 2:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[13608.104291] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
[13608.129907] sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[13608.130219] sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[13628.342227] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
[13628.350414] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
```

I can mount that CDROM but there's only Huawai Windows software on there.

I have set developer options in the phone and tried both MTP and PTP settings.
Android version on Huawai is 7.0
Local kernel is 5.10